# How to remove - Space between parent Menu and child menu

Tags: html, css

In the below drop down list, sub menus are getting displayed with lots of space, please see the below chart, Please let me know how do I avoid the space between parent Menu and Child menu.

```
 -----------------------------------------------------------
| PARENT1 |     
 -----------------------------------------------------------
  **SPACE IS HERE**

  --------
 |CHILD1  |     
  --------
 |CHILD2  |
  --------
```

My CSS Code :-

```
#navMenu {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#navMenu {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#navMenu ul{
margin:0;
padding:0;
 line-height:30px;
 z-index:1;

}

#navMenu li{
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
float:left;
position:relative;
 background:#8B0F2E;
    top: 51px;
    left: 10px;
}

#navMenu ul li a {
text-align:center;
font-family:"Comic Sans MS",cursive; 
text-decoration:none;
height:30px;
width:150px;
display:block;
color:#FFF;
border:0px solid #FFF;

}

#navMenu ul ul 
{
 position:absolute;
  visibility:hidden;
  top:32px;
}

#navMenu ul li:hover ul 
{
 visibility:visible;

}

#navMenu li:hover 
{
 background:#09F;   
}

#navMenu ul li:hover ul li a:hover 
{
 background:#CCC;
  color:#000;   
}

#navMenu a:hover
{
 color:#000;    
}

.clearFloat 
{
  clear:both;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
```

Comment: can you share the html

Comment: hard to say without the markup but at a first glance , why relative li has top left position ?, you can start from rectifying it

Comment: Since You not share html code i suppose problem cause `top:32px` in `#navMenu ul ul`... Try change to `top:100%;`... and, yes, share html too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response.My HTML Code :-
  <div id="wrapper">
        <div id ="navMenu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Products</a>
             <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Products1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Products2</a></li>
             </ul>

            </li> <!-- end main li -->
            </ul> <!-- end main ul -->
        <br class="clearFloat" /> 

        </div> <!-- end navmenu -->
    </div> <!-- End Wrapper -->